# Dataframe merging with src and dst keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have three dataframes

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'src': ['src1', 'src2', 'src3'],
               'dst': ['dst1', 'dst2', 'dst3']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'src': ['dst1', 'dst1', 'dst3'],
                   'dst': ['dstDst1', 'dstDst2', 'dstDst3']})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'src': ['dstDst3', 'dstDst3'],
                   'dst': ['dstDstDst1', 'dstDstDst2']})
```

I want to merge the three dataframes using the following rule:
Keep the initial src field and merge all the dst if there is a src->dst relationship that can backtrack to the src in df1. To be more concrete, the result of the merge is:

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'src': ['src1', 'src2', 'src3'],
                   'dst': ['dst1, dstDst1, dstDst2', 'dst2', 'dst3, dstDst3, dstDstDst1, dstDstDst2']})
```

NOTE: it is guaranteed that df2's src values are subsets of df1's dst values and df3's src values are subsets of df2's dst values.

I came up with this solution, would like to know if there are more elegant or idiomatic way of doing this.

```
df_collection = {}
df_collection[1] = df1
df_collection[2] = df2
df_collection[3] = df3

def merge(df1, df2):
    '''
    for each target in df1, find source in df2
    '''
    df3 = df1.copy(deep=True)
    # forward merge will be n complexity, ...save for later
    for i in range(0, len(df1)):
        for j in range(0, len(df2)):
            if df1.iloc[i]['dst'] == df2.iloc[j]['src']:
                df3.iloc[i]['dst'] = df3.iloc[i]['dst'] + ',' + df2.iloc[j]['dst']
    
    return df3

for i in range(3, 1, -1):
    df_collection[i-1] = merge(df_collection[i-1], df_collection[i])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the nested for loops by the following code.

### Code:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create the sample dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'src': ['src1', 'src2', 'src3'], 'dst': ['dst1', 'dst2', 'dst3']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'src': ['dst1', 'dst1', 'dst3'], 'dst': ['dstDst1', 'dstDst2', 'dstDst3']})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'src': ['dstDst3', 'dstDst3'], 'dst': ['dstDstDst1', 'dstDstDst2']})

# Merge the dataframes from back to front
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['src', 'dst'])
for i, _df in enumerate([df3, df2, df1]):
    df = _df.merge(df, how='left', left_on='dst', right_on='src', suffixes=('', f'_{i}'))
    df = df.groupby(['src', 'dst'], as_index=False)[f'dst_{i}'].agg(lambda s: [e for e in s if pd.notna(e)])
    df['dst'] = df.apply(lambda r: ', '.join([r['dst']] + r[f'dst_{i}']), axis=1)
    df = df[['src', 'dst']]

print(df)
```

### Output:

| src | dst |
| --- | --- |
| src1 | dst1, dstDst1, dstDst2 |
| src2 | dst2 |
| src3 | dst3, dstDst3, dstDstDst1, dstDstDst2 |